# Torque Specs for Honda Power Steering High Pressure Fitting

Tags: honda, accord, power-steering, torque-specification

I need the torque specs for connecting the high pressure power steering line to the base of the steering column in my 1998 Accord 6 cyl.

[This service manual](https://manuals.co/workshop/honda/accord/honda-accord-1998-2001-v-6-srs-supplement-service-manual/5874464/588) lists the torque specs for the 98-01 6 cyl Accord power steering system, but the high pressure line is labeled "return hose" and the low pressure line is labeled "feed hose."  My understanding is that this is a mislabeling, and so I am not sure whether the spec listed for the feed hose is actually the feed hose torque spec or is really the low pressure torque spec.

I suspect that the higher of the two specs is the one I need, since I would assume that the high pressure line would need to be torqued more.  But this could be a costly mistake if I am wrong.  Does anyone have more information regarding the torque specs for this fitting?

(It would also be helpful if any engineers could confirm my suspicion regarding the high pressure line receiving more torque or if owners of other Hondas know of a general trend among Honda engineers in designing the high pressure fitting to be torqued more.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High pressure hose is 37nm, return line is 28nm

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right, but notice that the lines point to the wrong fittings.  I found the same specs for a different model year with the lines pointing to the correct fittings [here](https://www.autozone.com/repairguides/Honda-Prelude-Accord-Civic-S2000-2001-2006/Power-Steering-Pump/Removal-Installation/_/P-0996b43f80375250). So far, tightening to the 37nm spec hasn't given me any problems, although some of the threads are still exposed, which is a bit odd.

Comment: There will be threads left exposed after proper torque.